# Jquery Live function is not working when used with keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use loadData() function to get data from my php script and I use another function to search from database. All works fine, but when I click on the search result, it's not loading the data. Here is the jquery functions I am using,

```
//Gets Data
function loadData(id)
{
loading_show();
$.ajax({
      url: "load_data.php",
      type: "post",
      data: "id="+id,
      success: function(data){
            loading_hide();
           $("#container_wrap_metro").html(data);
      },
      error:function(){
          alert("failure");
          $("#container_wrap_metro").html('Unable to process request!');
      }  
    }); 
}


//Search
$(function(){
  $("#result").keyup(function(){
    var q = $(this).val();
    $.get("results.php?q="+q, function(data){
    if(q){
        $(".side_container").html(data);
    } 
    else {
        $(".side_container").html("");
    }
  });
});
$('#b').live('click',function(){
  var page = $(this).attr('p');
  loadData(page);
  }); 
});
```

Comment: And what is $('#b')???

Comment: check the jQuery version as .live() is  Deprecated in version> 1.7

Comment: So your problem is with live(), read doc, all is explain...

Comment: @roasted 'b' is the id of the div (which holds the search result)

Comment: You should have post relevant html code. Which elements (#b,#result) if any are dynamically added???

Comment: I got a fix, #b is in results.php, so i added the the function to the results.php , now it works. Anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:

```
$(document).on('click','#b',function(){...}); //live equivalent
```

But better is to use closest static container:

```
$('#container_wrap_metro').on('click','#b',function(){...});
```

Answer (score 3):

.live() is  Deprecated so you can try .on() instead of .live().

http://api.jquery.com/live/  & http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

Which jQuery version are you using? the live function may be deprecated. Use .on() instead or .click() directly?

Comment: I use jquery 1.9.1 , Can you please suggest a way to write using .on() function, i am new to jquery

Comment: just replace "live" with "on" :) $("#b").on("click", function(){...});

Comment: No, you HAVE TO USE DELEGATION! Sorry for screaming

Comment: @roasted are you sure we have to? I am pretty sure it works without delegation, too. Else please explain than just shout

Comment: Ya, for dynamic element, you have to use delegation

Comment: But how can you be sure #b is dynamic?

Comment: Because, he was using live on it but maybe OP didn't know what he was doing

Comment: @Alex as roasted said the contents which has id = "b" is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Use `On`() as `live`() is deprecated.

```
$(document).on("click", "a.foo", fn);  //here a.foo is target
```

http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed

Comment: No, you are not using delegation here! BTW, there is a typo

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced live with on but it doesn't work for me. You can use .delegate()

In my case, I have written a click in the dynamically loaded content. When I updated the JQuery Library, the live stopped working & replaced it with delegate today.

See more information here: https://api.jquery.com/delegate/